# CakePHP 3.x - Validation with double association

Tags: validation, associations, cakephp-3.0

My database has Products, Shops and Branches. A Branch belongsTo a Shop, a Product belongsTo a Shop, but also optionally belongsTo a Branch.

**Question:** how do I (elegantly) validate from a Product whether the selected Branch is actually of the same Shop as the Shop selected for a Product?

I am already using buildRules like `$rules->existsIn` to verify whether the selected Shops and Branches exist in the first place. I feel like I should be able to extrapolate these functions so these are cross-checked as well.

*Note:* I am specifically asking for a validator. I realise I can add a constraint to the `Branches->find('list')->...` call so the user can only select the correct ones, however, having a validator as well seems safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this I solution I applied. I am not entirely satisfied because it doesn't seem elegant, but it certainly works:

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{

    // ...

    $rules->add(function ($entity, $options) {

        $branch = $this->Branches->find('all')->where(['Branch.id' => $entity->branch_id])->first();

        if (is_null($branch))
            return true;

        return $branch->shop_id == $entity->shop_id;

    }, 'branchCheck', ['errorField' => 'branch_id', 'message' => 'Branch does not belong to the specified shop']);
    // ...
}
```